# Can't connect to docker from Django, but can connect directly and in shell

Tags: python, django, docker, gunicorn

I have a Python/Django app that allows users to manage docker instances (with some abstraction).  I can control the docker containers from bash and from the Django shell just fine, but when I try to run the same code from my Django views, which are running through Gunicorn as the same user as I am running bash and the Django shell from, but Gunicorn gives the following output:

```bash
ERROR while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

The user that Gunicorn is running under is a member of the "docker" group, and I've restarted my server to be sure that the permissions should be in affect.  I'm not sure what else to check or do.